# Template style tag is not applied in Angular 5

Tags: css, angular, styling

Based on my intuitive understanding of how Web and Browsers work, and based on [this tutorial about styling in Angular 2](https://scotch.io/tutorials/all-the-ways-to-add-css-to-angular-2-components), I have this template:

```
<style>
   .price {
      background: red;
   }
</style>
<div class="price">$15.3</div>
```

Yet when I load this component, the price doesn't have red background.

What do I miss here?

Answer (score 0):

Nothing missing there. It's working for me. Try updating you node packages.